# Does two phase locking apply to each transaction, or the schedule as a whole?

Tags: transactions, locking, rdbms

## Background

Based on a question asked in the [Database Administrators Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/205201/does-two-phase-locking-apply-to-individual-transactions-or-the-schedule-as-a-wh), I seemed to have misunderstanding of what [2PL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_locking) is.

Here is the definition I understand from Database System: The Complete Book, Second Edition (ISBN 9780131873254) Page 900 - 901:

> There is a surprising condition, called *two-phase locking* (or *2PL*) under which we can guarantee that a legal schedule of consistent transactions is conflict-serializable:
>
> - In every transaction, all lock actions precede all unlock actions.
>
> The "two phases" referred to by 2PL are thus the first phase, where locks are obtained, and the second phase, where locks are relinquished. Two-phase locking is a condition, like consistency, on the order of actions in a transaction. A transaction that obeys the 2PL consition is said to be a *two-phased-locked transaction*, or 2PL transaction.

## Problem

I encountered this question in a homework, which posits the following problem:

> 1. Does the following dequence of actions follow 2PL? (L denotes Lock, U denotes Unlock, R denotes Read, W denotes Write, O denotes Output. So L1(A) denotes that Transaction 1 gets lock for A. We do not show Input here, but instead assume that that will happen along with R or W).
>
>    ```
>     a. Start T1.
>     b. L1(A)
>     c. R1(A)
>     d. W1(A)
>     e. O1(A)
>     f. Start T2.
>     g. L2(C)
>     h. L1(B)
>     i. U1(A)
>     j. L2(A)
>     k. W1(B)
>     l. Commit T1
>     m. R2(A)
>     n. W2(C)
>     o. U1(B)
>     p. Commit T2
>     q. U2(A)
>     r. U2(C)
>    ```

## My Answer

I understood 2PL to mean obtaining all locks before all unlocks **at the transaction level** as opposed to the schdule level as a whole, since that is what the text book (and the slide on the linked question from DBA Stack Exchange) said.  Given the above reasoning, I wrote this answer:

> Two phase locking: In every transaction, all lock actions precede all unlock 
>   actions.
>
> First phase: All locks obtained, second phase, locks relinquished.
>
> The sequence of actions depicted in the paper follows 2PL because all the 
>   lock actions in each transaction precede all lock actions.  A and B are 
>   locked by transaction one and there is no unlocking in between these two 
>   locks.  Unlocking only happens after both A and B are locked.  For 
>   transaction 2, A and C are locked before any unlocking happens. Hence, since 
>   all locking actions within the sequence of actions occur before any 
>   unlocking occurs, this sequence satisfies 2PL.

Thus **2PL is followed**....

...however, this was marked wrong for the following reason:

> All locks should be obtained before any unlocks 
>   and this isn't the case here. T1 unlocks A signalling that no more locking 
>   should happen from any transaction, but the next action involves T2 calling 
>   lock on A. This is why I marked you down.

Hence, I am not sure if I misinterpreted something here and wanted to get a solid answer.

## Question

What determines if a database schedule is in 2PL, the order of locking and unlocking within each transaction at a time, or the order of locking and unlocking in the schedule as a whole?

Comment: I can't make any sense of your teacher's explanation. It is not a justification that you are wrong.

Comment: Edited to particular situation, with better presentation. Question did not refer to a 2PL set, but rather "following 2PL".  The protocol is defined in the textbook definition I give. The exact question is given. The protocol (as given the textbook definition) is followed. If we are speaking in terms of a schedule being in a set, then this schedule IS in the set.  My confusion came from authoritative sources (i.e. professors and grad TA's) contradicting my reasoning, and it affecting my grade.